# How to implement opt-in and opt-out functionality in braintree drop-in UI

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-vault

I have added Braintree drop-in UI in my angular project.
In that, I am showing exiting payment methods from the vault.
Now I want to implement functionality so that when the user checked the checkbox, in that case, the only card(Payment method) will add to vault.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, I recommend contacting [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

For your use case, I recommend using the API to store cards in the Vault, rather than the built-in functionality in the Drop-in UI. Reason being, it'd be much simpler to set the [`vaultCard`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/module-braintree-web-drop-in.html#~cardCreateOptions) option to `false`, rather than dynamically updating the Drop-in configuration.

From there, you can submit the payment method nonce of the selected card to your server to perform a [`PaymentMethod.create()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create) API request. As an example, here is how a request may look like using the .NET SDK:

```
var request = new PaymentMethodRequest
{
    CustomerId = "THE_CUSTOMER_ID",
    PaymentMethodNonce = NonceFromTheClient
};

Result<PaymentMethod> result = gateway.PaymentMethod.Create(request);
```

Using the payment method nonce provided from the Drop-in in the above request will store that payment method in your Vault.